# Would this question about symptom control be on topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm new to this SE site and did some poking about in meta to see if I could determine if my question was on topic or not. I couldn't be 100% sure one way or the other, so I thought I'd just ask directly. Would the following question be considered on topic?

---

### <strike>How to control the vomit response?</strike>

I came down with the flu about three days ago. Mostly typical symptoms: fever, chills, body aches, extreme exhaustion, etc... The only symptoms that haven't been an issue is nausea or upset stomach. What's hitting me the hardest is the exhaustion. The reason that is the biggest deal is because I absolutely must take the dog out at least twice a day. Even a short five minute walk of just 100-200 feet leaves me with dry heaves. It's like I tried to run a marathon without any practice.

I've looked online for options to control the vomit response and found almost everything refers to ways to counter upset stomach, nausea, motion sickness, side effects of other medications, and so on. Other solutions are meant to calm things down after the vomiting event.

I would like to prevent the vomiting before it even starts. Are there any methods or medicines that can suppress the general vomit response?

---

V2

### General purpose vomit response control?

Is there a general purpose [antiemetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiemetic) for vomit response control?
Many vomit control solutions are focused on specific causes for the vomiting. Some examples along with treatments:

- Illness: bismuth subsalicylate(Pepto-Bismol, Kaopectate), clear
  fluids
- Upset stomach: bismuth subsalicylate, clear fluids, peppermint
  tea, bland food such as crackers or toast
- Nausea: ginger, breath
  control techniques, acupressure, Lorazepam, aromatherapy
- [Motion sickness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_sickness#Treatment): Dramamine, scopolamine, dimenhydrinate, dexamphetamine
- Side effects of other medications: Zofran, cannabis, Anzemet, Kytril,
  Sancuso
- [Pregnancy](https://www.aafp.org/afp/2003/0701/p121.html): ginger, pyridoxine, doxylamine, accupressure
- Alcohol: Vitamin B6, clear fluids, bland food such as crackers or
  toast

What I'm interested in is medicines or methods to suppress the vomit response in general. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: This is a great question! By all means post it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and everything. The question has been posted. Hopefully the tags are the right ones to use as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question can be found [here](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It's the part in **bold** text:

> If your question is a request for medical advice for you or others, it
>   is off-topic and instead should be directed to a physician. Such
>   questions will be closed here.

So when I read the first few words of your question -- "I came down with the flu" -- I knew it was going to be off topic.

However....

The very last sentence of your question would be on topic if that's all your question contained. So you would have to delete or de-personalize almost your entire question with the exception of that last sentence.

We also require questions to display some degree of prior research on your part, so your second paragraph would probably suffice and should be left in (adding a link or two would make it even better).

Thanks for asking before posting. Most people don't bother, which is why we have a high closure rate.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to revise it next time I'm on the computer.

Comment: Updated. Removed all personal anecdotes, added some references.